# VirtualBox Ubuntu VM doesn't automatically sync time with host even with Guest Additions installed

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, synchronization, virtualbox, system-clock

I'm running a Ubuntu VM with VirtualBox and I have both the `dkms` and `virtualbox-guest-additions` packages installed. I read in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/335873/149613) that the system clock should sync with the host automatically with the Guest Additions, but mine doesn't seem to be doing that. What are some possible reasons / how do I rectify this? I've tried searching for this all over but most of the hits I get off Google tell you how to *disable* the automatic time sync, not enable it.

My host machine is running OS X 10.8, if that's of any help.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, you should ask on [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Just flagged it for moderator attention. Thanks @Gary.

Comment: Sorry we didn't get to your flag sooner. I see you've posted it there yourself so I'll close this now.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for following up.

Comment: Figured out the answer; I've added it here: http://superuser.com/questions/649661/virtualbox-ubuntu-vm-doesnt-automatically-sync-time-with-host-even-with-guest-a